# how to extend usb c cable (usb 3)

Tags: usb-c, adapter, ssd, apple, m.2

its look like this qus is simple but its not at all
see here what i did

i have m1 air base model, and i have lack of capacity, its only 256 so i thought i need more space

so i thought why not put m.2 inside the divece, (of course i know that it not support that nativly)
[image]
so i opened the lap and i found place will be enouph to put m.2 with all adapters to usb inside the macbook air it self as you will see in photos
and i used usb to m.2 with lowerst thinkness avalible in market (around 3mm)
so i can close the cover easly. so every thing perfect

i choosed good usba to usbc adapter that support usb 3 i removed usb 3 part and i solders cables

then i did same thing for m.2 adapter, all cable connected well, and ohm between the cables is near to zero

when i connect it adapter work but m.2 no

i saw this problem before when i was choosing usba to usb c adapters, some of chinese bad ones did same thing same problem exacly, so i think my cables not best idea

but i cant understand why it not working iam sure if i connect mouse or kayboard it will work, but why m.2 not working even in usb2 speed

these photos of my great idea i hope you can help me guys iam counting on you all
[image]enter image description here
[image]

[image]

Comment: We can't decipher how you connected the wires. Please show what was your intention how to connect them to even know if your plan was OK or not, then if the plan for connections is OK then there may be an error in the wiring which can be identified. But, as you did not use correct wires (twisted differential pair cables) the high speed signals can't likely work throug your random airwires.

Comment: High speed USB signaling does not work over random individual wires straggled all over the place like that. You *might* have better luck if you cut a piece out of an old USB cable and use that instead, but only if you use the correct wire pairs in the cable.

Comment: connect the wires by solder, so i thought it will work

Comment: after i reamoved the the wires and i connect them with usb c male , good one 
so it worked in some divices in usb 2 speed, 
in some devices it didnt work at all 

so i understood that signal have problem 
my thinking now that because this m.2 adapter had dirctly usb connected 
so the chip inside do not expect long distance
so it not give that powerfull signal

spically if iam using bad cables

so i bought another adapter with usb c female, and cable attached 
so i will use them to do the project again but in easer way 

but more expensvie 
if it went good i will share